# How to vectorize a threshold on a slice in a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to vectorize a threshold on a slice in a 3D array.
Unfortunately, the threshold is being applied to all 3 values in the dimension.
The only way I can think of is to extract slice 1, process that then put it back into the array but I'm sure there is a better way.
Here is some code to explain what I'm doing and what I'm trying to do.
Thank you very much for any assistance.
J

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(18).reshape(3, 2, 3)
arr[ arr[:,:,1] < 10 ] = 0
```

Gives :

```
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

I was hoping for :

```
array([[[ 0,  0,  2],
        [ 3,  0,  5]],

       [[ 6,  0,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

Comment: Is your threshold 10 or 20?

Comment: Thanks @PaulH, yes, typo in my simplification of the original problem

Comment: In the future, you should edit your question to remove such errors

Comment: Thanks Paul, yes, you are correct. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
arr[:, :, 1][arr[:, :, 1] < 10] = 0
```

This will create a boolean mask for the second element of dimension 3 of `arr` with: `arr[:, :, 1] < 10`. This boolean mask is then used to only index its specific array slice.

A nice feature to make selections of the last dimension more readable is the ellipsis `...`. It will slice all axes before the explicitly indexed axis.

```
print(arr[..., 1])
# Out: array([[ 1,  4],
              [ 7, 10],
              [13, 16]])
```

In this case, you can for example use it like this:

```
slc = (..., 1)
arr[slc][arr[slc] < 10] = 0
```

Comment: `slc = (..., 1)` Is that new? I fully expected a syntax error here. Pity it doesn't work with slice notation in general. Still, I find `slc = arr[..., 1]` `slc[slc<10] = 0` a bit more elegant.

Comment: Honestly: I don't know since how long it has been implemented, but I guess it is at least two years. What do you mean with slice notation in general? In my special case, I re-use indices several times for many different arrays of the same shape. Thus I tend to store the indices as in `slc = (..., 1)` or `slc = (slice(1, 2), slice(2, 10, 2))` while naming the extracted views with somethin like `arr_view`, but I guess this is just personal preference. :)

Comment: I meant things like `slc = (:, :, 1)` still don't seem to work. Btw., in case you are not aware of it, you can write `slc = np.s_[1:2, 2:10:2]` for your second example. `np.s_` is I believe a hack that hijacks the `__getitem__` method to intercept any legal indexing expression. I find it a bit more intuitive than explicitly writing `slice(1, 2)` etc. but it's presumably a mattter of taste.

Comment: Oh cool, in fact I was not aware of being able to use `np.s_`. Many thanks, I'll definetely use it several times. Yep, having the possibility to store slices using slice notation would be a nice feature...

Comment: Thanks @Scotty1-. I really appreciate the answer and the suggestion of the ellipsis notation. It took me a good hour of playing with code to get my head around it all. :-)

Answer (score 4):

We can simply use the mask of comparisons to index along the first two axes and use the slicing on the last axis, giving us a compact way like so -

```
arr[arr[:,:,1]<10, 1] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: arr = np.arange(18).reshape(3, 2, 3)

In [48]: arr[arr[:,:,1] <10,1] = 0

In [49]: arr
Out[49]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  2],
        [ 3,  0,  5]],

       [[ 6,  0,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution, but timings show that it is 35% slower than `arr[arr[:,:,1]<10, 1] = 0`. It seems like additional array copies are made somewhere in this solution.

Comment: @Scotty1- Yeah I could verify those. Think it's the difference between slicing and masking in one step shown in this post versus slicing and then masking, so the masking has to work on a smaller data and the latter is winning because of it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I found both solutions (@Scotty1- and @Divakar) intuitive (and to me, instructive). Upvoted both! But @Scotty, your comment about "35% slower than `arr[arr[:,:,1]<10, 1] = 0`" confuses me. How can a solution be slower than itself? Is there a typo error in that comment?

Comment: @fountainhead He meant between mine and his, i.e. between `arr[arr[:,:,1]<10, 1]` and `arr[:, :, 1][arr[:, :, 1] < 10]`.

Comment: @fountainhead Thanks for the upvote! Yeah, Divakar is right. I copied the wrong code snippet. I realized it 6 minutes after posting it -> too late for an edit. :)

Comment: Thanks @Divakar your comments have given me a great deal more insight